# What is the use of Ext.loader.paths in extjs4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, sencha-architect

Can anybody tell what is use of Ext.loader.paths  How to use Ext.loader.paths in extjs .can anybody provide example

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason is to let you run different namespaces in different folders.

Another is to let you find namespaces on different servers. Examples below.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    paths: {
        'my.namespace.module': 'app/module/mymodule',
        'Ext.ux':'http//extjs.cachefly.net/ext-4.1.1-gpl/examples/ux'
    }
});
```